# Win32 C - Control IDs of dynamically created controls?

Tags: c, winapi, win32gui, docking

I'm trying to create popout windows (like the dockable panes in Visual Studio). I need to create splitter controls to allow resizing of the controls when they're attached. I'm basing my design around the MFC docking panes and I'm trying not to hardcode docking regions.

Ideally I'd not like to have a fixed amount of sliders that are created hidden, but rather a variable amount depending on the location of each attached window. My current thoughts:

1. Use `SubtractRect()` to subtract the `RECT` of the attached window from that of the effective client area.
2. Create a slider for each edge of the control that is not on the edge of the main window's effective client area.

However when using `CreateWindow()` ideally a control ID would be passed in which is usually hard-coded in `Resource.h`, which then makes dynamic creation of controls tricky. Not to mention recalculating window sizes based on the location of the slider(s).

I'd thought about allocating an ID range to use for dynamic controls so I could start off with `#define IDC_SPLITTER1 100` for example, then increment from this value for each splitter created. I've seen `_APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE` mentioned which I believe is used in MFC, but only for the IDE?

Sorry if this question is a bit wish-washy, I'm really struggling to get my head around this.

Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome to use whatever algorithm you like to generate IDs dynamically. For example, you might decide that all of your fixed IDs are in the 100-999 range, and all your dynamic ones start at 1000. Totally up to you how you want to do it.

Comment: Do you *have* to give them an ID? The panes will usually go inside the main non-dialog window, so there's no expectation for them to have IDs.

Comment: Control IDs are not *required* to work with UI controls, especially when they are created dynamically in code. All you really need is the HWNDs.

Comment: @yak Yes, you **must** assign an ID to any child window. The signature for `CreateWindow` doesn't allow you to omit that value.

Comment: @IInspectable: I see what you mean, but in a non-dialog window the IDs aren't used, and therefore can all be zero. In practice that's what happening in pretty much any non-dialog based app with controls.

Comment: @yak You are confusing two unrelated concepts: Use and uniqueness. Child window IDs are **always** used. Child window IDs are not strictly required to be unique. You do not have a say in whether the IDs are used, but you get to decide which ones need to be unique.

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't. What I mean is that, even if the window is assigned any arbitrary ID, that id still isn't going to be used if you don't call functions like `GetDlgItem` and use the `hwnd` rather than the `id` in parent notifications to identify the child.

Comment: @yak Which is precisely what I described: *"You do not have a say in whether the IDs are used, but you get to decide which ones need to be unique."* This statement is true, irrespective of whether the parent is a dialog or not.

Comment: That seems like a good point about whether I'd actually need to assign an ID or not. Though the handles would probably have to be stored in a struct accessed using `GetWindowLongPtr()` rather than using `GetDlgItem()`. Then there'd need to be some code logic to determine which slider is the correct one.